# Slicing bivariate exponential generating functions on x and y

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity, generating-functions

Let $F(x, y) = e^{y D(x)}$ be a generating function for sets of objects enumerated by $D(x)$ that also keeps track of the number of sets (enumerated by the variable $y$, while $x$ enumerates the total number of atoms in objects). Then,

- $[y^k] F(x, y) = \frac{D(x)^k}{k!}$ is the EGF for sets of $k$ objects;
- $G_n(y) =\left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right] F(x, y)$ is the OGF for sets that overall have exactly $n$ atoms.

Assuming that $D(x)$ is known modulo $x^{n+1}$, is there any sub-quadratic algorithm to find $G_n(y)$?

Some standard examples are

- $D(x) = e^x - 1$ (corresponds to the Stirling numbers of the second kind),
- $D(x) = \log(1+x)$ (corresponds to the Stirling numbers of the first kind).

In these particular cases it's possible to find $G_n(y)$ in $O(n \log n)$, as it's equivalent to finding $s(n, k)$ or $S(n, k)$ for all $k$ with a fixed $n$. But I don't see any simple generalisations...

Comment: is a binomial Sheffer polynomial sequence, characterized by, among others, Roman and Rota. These have raising (and lowering) operators as generators, but I've never considered the computational complexity. Perhaps the CC is discussed somewhere for binomial Sheffer sequences in general.

Comment: You mean [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_type), right? Thanks, that's a nice starting point!

Comment: Can you point me to some resources on how to actually find $Q(D)$ such that $Q p_n(x) = np_{n-1}(x)$ if $p_n(x)$ are generated by $e^{xf(t)}$? The Wiki doesn't give it explicitly...

Comment: Ah, apparently $Q(D)$ is the compositional inverse of $f(x)$?

Comment: Try  https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2023/07/04/the-umbral-compositional-inverse-of-a-sheffer-polynomial-sequence-and-its-lowering-and-raising-operators/ and https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2023/06/30/reps-of-the-lowering-destruction-annihilation-operator-for-binomial-sheffer-polynomial-sequences/

Comment: For some reason, the first part of the first sentence of my initial comment has been omitted. It read: With $D(x)$ analytic about the origin and $D(0)=0$ and $dD(0)/dx \neq 0$, the set of polynomials $G_n(y)$ . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $D(0) = 0$, we can restate the problem as $F(x, y) = A(x)^y$ for $A(x) = e^{D(x)}$.

It means that we can find $G_n(k)$ for any number $k$ as
$$
G_n(k) = \left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right] A(x)^k.
$$
So, if we're able to do this, we can interpolate $G_n(y)$ from $G_n(k)$ for $k=1..n$ in $O(n \log^2 n)$ and vice versa. Thus, the problems of finding $G_n(y)$ from the definition in the question, and finding $[x^n] A(x)^k$ for $k=1..n$  for a given power series $A(x)$ are somewhat equivalent.

On the other hand, consider a polynomial $B(x) = b_0 + b_1 x + \dots + b_m x^m$. We can express
$$
[x^n] B(A(x)) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m b_k [x^n] A(x)^k,
$$
meaning that we can compute $[x^n] B(A(x))$ in $O(n)$ if we know all $[x^n] A(x)^k$. That being said, if we can find $G_n(y)$ for any $D(x)$ in $O(f(n))$, then we can also find $[x^n] B(A(x))$ in $O(f(n) + n \log^2 n)$.

On the other hand, at the moment the fastest algorithm to do this directly has a complexity of $O((n \log n)^{3/2})$ (see [here](https://www.texmacs.org/joris/fastcomp/fastcomp.html)), meaning that any algorithm to compute $G_n(y)$ in the generic setting is unlikely to be faster than that.

Whether this complexity is achievable remains to be seen, but probably the whole problem can also be reduced to polynomial composition or compositional inversion.